# Marionette region does not show view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am trying to follow Brian Mann's tutorials and I am stuck at showing the footer.

In my controller I have this:

```
@Demo.module "Footer.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  Show.Controller =
    showFooter: ->
      footerView = @getFooterView()
      App.footerRegion.show footerView

    getFooterView: ->
      new Show.FooterView()
```

And in my view:

```
@Demo.module "Footer", (Footer, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  API =
    showFooter: ->
      Footer.Show.Controller.showFooter();

  Footer.on "start", ->
    API.showFooter()
```

What is interesting, is that, if I do `console.log footerView` before showing it in the region, I get a `FooterView` like this:

```
FooterView {render: function, options: Object, events: undefined, cid: "view2", $el: jQuery.fn.init[1]…}
  $el: jQuery.fn.init[1]
  _events: Object
  _isRendered: true
  _isShown: true
  _listenId: "l3"
  _listeningTo: Object
  cid: "view2"
  el: div
  events: undefined
  isClosed: false
  options: Object
  render: function () { [native code] }
  __proto__: ctor
```

And when I inspect `@Demo.footerRegion` in the console, I get this:

```
Marionette.Region {options: Object, el: "#footer-region", $el: jQuery.fn.init[0], currentView: 
  FooterView, on: function…}
  $el: jQuery.fn.init[0]
  currentView: FooterView
  el: "#footer-region"
  options: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

As shown above, the `footerRegion's` `currentView` is a `FooterView`, but when I inspect the DOM, `footerRegion` is empty.

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: can you upload this code to jsfiddle?

Comment: Does your footer view actually have content (i.e. a template with something to display) ?

Comment: I found the problem: I hadn't started the module!!! I know it's so stupid. So, `App.module("Footer").start()` fixed it.